# How much memory are used by perticular session during run time in MySQL 5.1 community version?

Tags: mysql, linux

Is it possible to find out how much memory is used by particular session?A user was asked me how much memory is utilized by particular session running in MySQLl 5.1 community version server. 
Kindly provide the solutions thanx in advance.

Comment: `Show session status` outputs your own session. Maybe [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/55996/39160) helps you to query the information_schema tables.

Comment: Looks to me like there is one answer ("Not in 5.1") and the Answer below (for 5.7) is not "too long for this format".  Take it off Hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL 5.7 (still in development as of this post, but soon to be released) is the first version to include memory profiling.

You have to enable memory profiling on the setup instruments (it is disabled by default) ans then you can check it with this [sys view](https://github.com/MarkLeith/mysql-sys/blob/master/views/p_s/memory_by_thread.sql):

You can get results such as:

```
mysql> select * from sys.memory_by_thread_by_current_bytes limit 5;
+-----------+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| thread_id | user           | current_count_used | current_allocated | current_avg_alloc | current_max_alloc | total_allocated |
+-----------+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|         1 | sql/main       |              29333 | 166.02 MiB        | 5.80 KiB          | 131.13 MiB        | 196.00 MiB      |
|        55 | root@localhost |                175 | 1.04 MiB          | 6.09 KiB          | 350.86 KiB        | 67.37 MiB       |
|        58 | root@localhost |                236 | 368.13 KiB        | 1.56 KiB          | 312.05 KiB        | 130.34 MiB      |
|       904 | root@localhost |                 32 | 18.00 KiB         | 576 bytes         | 16.00 KiB         | 6.68 MiB        |
|       970 | root@localhost |                 12 | 16.80 KiB         | 1.40 KiB          | 16.00 KiB         | 1.20 MiB        |
+-----------+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

Before 5.6, you had to relay on [external tools](http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/01/09/profiling-mysql-memory-usage-with-valgrind-massif/) that you may not want to run in production. @rene's recomendation on profiling session status variables could be a better bet.

Comment: Afaik MariaDB has per-session memory usage stats, too

Comment: Thank u @jynus but I am using MySQL 5.1 is there any possibility?..if there plz help...